# Each query run in pgadmin fails

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Any SELECT query run in pgadmin4 (v1.1) fails with error: Fetching Type Error.

```
2016-12-02 09:19:50,046: SQL    pgadmin:        Polling result for (Query-id: 7482427)
2016-12-02 09:19:50,072: SQL    pgadmin:        Execute (dict) for server #1 - CONN:9467479 (Query-id: 8631388):
SELECT oid, format_type(oid,null) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid IN (user_data) ORDER BY oid;
2016-12-02 09:19:50,073: ERROR  pgadmin:        Failed to execute query (execute_dict) for the server #1- CONN:9467479 (Query-id: 8631388):
Error Message:ERROR:  column "user_data" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e(oid,null) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid IN (user_data)...
                                                         ^
```

View Data -> View All Rows ends the same way.

The problem affects all tables in database. Other statements (like INSERT) works fine. SELECTs run in psql works also fine.
I was testing as simplest queries as:

```
 SELECT * FROM "table";
```

I am running postgresql-9.6 on Linux.

Comment: It's a built-in query against `pg_type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Error Message:ERROR:  column "user_data" does not exist
```

You should be sure that you have `user_data` column in your `pg_type` table.

Comment: `pg_type` is a built-in table, and they seem to be experiencing problems based on queries generated by PgAdmin. `pg_type`'s columns all start with `typ` so I don't know where `user_data` comes from; that string does not appear in PgAdmin's source code, though this looks like a PgAdmin-generated internal query.

Comment: It looks like, there is bug in PgAdmin4. PgAdmin3 - works well.

Comment: By the way, if the problem happens because of pgAdmin (it happens sometimes, I came across it too) you can use navicat too. It is very usefull too. @kbzowski